# how to show text to another div id in another page in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a form where I have submitted the text from the user input but I dont know how to show the text to a different div in a another page in javascript. can anyone help me solve this issue? thanks for the help.

here is my script:

```
     <input onclick="addTheEvent(); return false;" type="submit" value="Add to list" class="btn btn-primary" />

 <script>

    var addToTheContent = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var scheduleEvent = document.getElementById("scheduleStartTime");
    var candidateId = document.getElementById('candId');
    var getCandId = document.getElementById("candId");

  var displayCandId = getCandId.options[getCandId.selectedIndex].value;

  function addTheEvent() {


            addToTheContent.innerHTML = "name  = " +
            displayCandId + " at " + scheduleEvent.value;
       }

   </script>
```

Another page: (I want to add the value to show in my content div that is in another page)

```
 <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>
```

Comment: Either pass it as query string or use localstorage

Comment: @SagarV can you show a reference or a snippet code to make it work?

Comment: Is the other page in the same domain? If so, you can use cross-document messaging. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: @thog314 Basically, I am in contact page and I want to get the id from Home page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use a single page application (SPA).

> A single-page application is an app that works inside a browser and does not require page reloading during use.

But the SPA is quite a massive theme. It's required for knowledge of the usage [browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) , etc. So you should try to use variant #2

2. You can use local [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) of the browser where you can save your data

   ```
   localStorage.setItem("key","value") //set value into local storage
   localStorage.getItem("key") // get value
   ```

   The "key" is an any string

On another page use

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {  
    const dataFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('key');
    document.querySelector("#content").innerHTML = dataFromLocalStorage; })
```

Comment: can you show a reference or a snippet to see of how it works?

Comment: so, if I put the localstorage in my function how to access onto another page?

Comment: the second-row show you how - localStorage.getItem("key") -> key is the access to your value

Comment: so this will work on the fly on my another page? am I going to access the `content` id ?

Comment: do you get what I mean @Gorr1995

Comment: true, you should try it. read the article which I have showed to you. I prefer to use the server-side for managing the submitted data

Comment: but do you understand my question - of what I am trying to access?

Comment: You want to write down some data into local storage and have access to it on any page of your site